# Restore database from deleted heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm guessing that my situation cannot be fixed, but I thought I'd ask out of desperation.

Today, in attempting to fix a corrupt git repository, I made the incredible mistake of deleting my app from heroku without first backing up the production database. Is there any possible course of action that I might take to retrieve the data from that database?

In the future, what are your recommended methods for backing up your development database?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: You should probably reach out to their support team.

Comment: Do you have any local clone?

Comment: @ElpieKay, how would a local clone help?

Comment: @Chris I've never used heroku but the app created on heroku is a git repo, right? You could push you local clone back to heroku. The unsynced diff maybe lost.

Comment: @ElpieKay, the OP is specifically asking about the app's _database_. That almost certainly isn't part of the repository (and if it is there are other problems to deal with).

Comment: @Chris sorry and thanks. I've learned something new.

Comment: @ElpieKay, no need to apologize. If you had a way to recover the production database from a local clone I'd have been genuinely impressed.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have contacted Heroku's support team.

Comment: I'd definitely contact heroku... there's a (small) chance they have their own backups and yours might not be deleted yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Heroku Postgres, it's possible Heroku could restore it from some internal backup, but it's pretty unlikely unless you are an enterprise level customer. If you are using Mongo, and use M-Lab and have a paid account, the destruction of the app shouldn't have deleted the database. (not 100% on that...) Otherwise it depends on how your db was set up.

In the future utilize the Heroku tools to preform manual backups (especially before any potential situations of complications, as you are now fully aware of), or set up scheduled backups to S3 for maximum data redundancy.

Sorry to hear about it! It's never fun.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Heroku customer support WAS able to restore the missing database!

Comment: Hi @Jeff Zivkovic, im facing the exact same situation, could you please let me know how did you sort it out?

Comment: @tomascharad.  I believe that I simply e-mailed Heroku.  From what I remember, they just asked me a few questions.  A few hours later, my database was fully restored!  I hope it works out for you as well.